# I've accidentily deleted /etc/apparmor/, what should I do to restore it?

Tags: debian, apt, apparmor

I accidentally deleted the /etc/apparmor/ folder on my debian 4.19.28-2 box by having the wrong folder selected in a gui file browser.

My questions are:

1. Should I be worried?

```
#apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
```

2. Is there a way to find what should have been in that folder?  Perhaps a way to search apt for all packages that provided a file in that folder?  Or perhaps a way to know from the output of `apparmor_status`?

```
#apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
13 profiles are loaded.
13 profiles are in enforce mode.
   {snip 13 lines}
0 profiles are in complain mode.
83 processes have profiles defined.
83 processes are in enforce mode.
   {snip 83 lines}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reinstall it with

```
apt-get install --reinstall apparmor
```

Comment: I believe I had actually tried this, but a reboot was needed to clear everything up after this.  Probably because some applications (docker for example) dynamically inject their apparmor rules.

Comment: Could be worth doing `dpkg -S /etc/apparmor/` and look at what packages are displayed. There could be other packages affected like apparmor-utils .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you made no config changes, etc. then you should be able to download the relevant `.deb` file, convert it to a `.tgz` with `alien`, extract it in a temp spot, and move the files to the appropriate places.

Comment: No need to use alien, the `deb` file is just an `ar` archive, so you can extract it with `ar -x path/to/pkg.deb`.